# Web framework with user-friendly desktop deployment?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, ria, offline

I'm building a web app with Backbone.js (I'm not tied to Backbone yet though). I need a back-end framework only for persistence to a database via a RESTful API. However, I also need to able to deploy it as a 'desktop' app for off-line use, i.e. running a local server and launching a browser window, but I don't want users to have to start a server from the command line to run the application.

I can use SQLite as a database since it's only a single user application, it's just the framework that I'm stuck on. I have looked at the following:

- Rails and Django: Default web servers are too flimsy, requires Ruby/Python and runs from the command line. I'm aware of the Bitnami stacks but at 99mb it's too big of a dependency and not exactly hidden from the user.
- Sproutcore: Run from command line, also too bulky.
- Pyjamas Desktop - Depends on MSHTML which I suspect limits my ability to use HTML5 features.

I'm leaning towards creating a Java app that starts a Scala/Lift server instance and opens a web browser, then sits in the system tray (kind of like WAMP). Is anyone familiar with a tool or framework built for user-friendly deployment as a standalone desktop app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web2py has a standalone deploy-to-desktop feature with no dependency on Python: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14#How-to-distribute-your-applications-as-binaries

As Eydun said, [phpdock](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm) is an option but it's commercially licensed .

I settled on using Java/Spring/H2/Hibernate/Jetty. I find that Jetty serves requests VERY quickly so the application looks real-time when launched in a browser. There is a tutorial on embedding the Jetty server [here](http://steveliles.github.com/setting_up_embedded_jetty_8_and_spring_mvc_with_maven.html). I imagine it's quite trivial to build a GUI that launches the server and a browser.

Another Java option is to use the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org), which may be more at home to those coming from a Django/Rails background. However, the documentation for ["creating a standalone version of your application"](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionDist) for Play 2.0+ indicates that they have ditched using Java EE containers (Tomcat/Jetty) and WAR files in favor of running the JARs with the bundled copy of JBoss Netty, so it may take a bit of work to get it running the way you want it.

I would recommend the Play Framework approach if you're OK with using/learning Scala.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if PHP is an option for you? Then I would recommend [phpdock](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phpdock.htm).